# How to apply same Jquery required validation on more than one textfields

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code. this work perfect when all three fields are empty and show three error message. but in my case there is only one field and its has three parts like "12345-1234567-7".. in first texbox only enter 5 digits, in second only 7 digit and in third only 1 digit to be entered.

How to apply required validation if any one of these to be empty then single error message is shown?

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#myfrom").validate({
         if(#cnic_1)
          rules: {
             cnic_1: "required",
             cnic_2: "required",
             cnic_3: "required"
             },
             messages: {
                cnic_1: "Required Field",
                cnic_2: "Required Field",
                cnic_3: "Required Field",
             }
         });
    });

</script>


<form id="myfrom" action="" method="get">
        <label>CNIC:</label>
        <input name="cnic_1" id="cnic_1" type="text" />
        <input name="cnic_2" id="cnic_2" type="text" />
        <input name="cnic_3" id="cnic_3" type="text" />
        <input name="" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please do not rollback to unreadable edits.

Answer (score 0):

According to api ( http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ ), it should look like this:

```
cnic_1:
     rules: {
    cnic_1:  {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5,
      maxlength: 5,
      number: true
    },
    cnic_2:  {
      required: true,
      minlength: 7,
      maxlength: 7,
      number: true
    },
    cnic_3:  {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 1,
      digits: true
    }
    },
```

Comment: But I think that in my case, simple message-field is required is not enought, you would have to upgrade it to something like : "You required 7 digit number"